# Who gets the bill?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, contacts

I apologize if I missed some basic Civi concept, but who gets the invoice when a 3rd party registers users with online registration? Most of our client's contacts are 3rd party association managers, who register their board members. Today, the invoice and billing was assigned to the first name  registered, who was not the person doing the registration.  Is there some way to select who pays the tab when they hit submit?

(Ed.) This is using WP

Comment: Pages that allow you to create two individuals when making a payment (that isn't an event) isn't a built-in function of Civi; are you using Caldera forms or an extension to accomplish this?  If you're not sure, a link to the page in question could help.

Comment: Caldera is not a part of our workflow, but I'll take a look. My first concern, would be dividing data that would best be handled exclusively in Civi. I did briefly peek at Caldera and it shows some promise.